# AngularJS - Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I get an error:

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string

I read and apply the others recommendation. But I have not solved the problem.

Here is my code:

**controller.js**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
   .controller('DashCtrl', function ($scope,$ionicScrollDelegate,SocketService) {
      var me = this;
      me.messages = [];
      $scope.sendTextMessage = function() {
        var msg = {
          'text': me.messages
      }
      me.messages.push(msg);
      $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollBottom();
      me.messages = '';
      SocketService.emit('mesaj', msg);
   };
});
```

**services.js**

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])
   .service('SocketService', ['socketFactory'],
      function SocketService(socketFactory) {
        return socketFactory({
           ioSocket: io.connect('http://l92.168.1.27:3000')
        });
   });
```

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: Improved formatting, improve the view of the error

Answer (score 0):

Remove second parameter when declaring angular module.

So change this : `angular.module('starter.controllers', [])`
To this: `angular.module('starter.controllers')`

Comment: He is probably creating an Angular module... So in that case the `[]` need to persist...

Comment: How can you assume such thing when having two different js files `controller.js` and `service.js` and he's creating the angular module on both ??? Normally there is an `angular.module.js` where someone creates the `angular.module` and then while he creates other controllers or services he has to make a reference like I present on my answer. Also you might not devote an answer by assuming things.

Comment: Easy man... At first I didn't downvote your answer ... secondly, I just added a comment, explicitly mentioning 'probably'. It was just an addition to your answer. Be happy :)

Comment: I am sorry.. I  thought, and this is the right thing, that you devoted and then added  the reason why you did this. But yeah I assume that he is creating the module in some other file rather than these two.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not @Korte

Comment: Is there some other place where you create the `angular.module` ?

Answer (score 0):

Two things that jump out at me;

1) no injections; fix these lines to:

```
.controller('DashCtrl', ['scope', '$ionicScollDelegate', 'SocketService', function ($scope,$ionicScrollDelegate,SocketService){
```

and

```
.service('SocketService', ['socketFactory',
```

Although that last line, I would simply write the SocketService() function into it like so:

```
app
 .service('SocketService', ['socketFactory', function(socketFactory) {
   return socketFactory({
     ioSocket: io.connect('http://l92.168.1.27:3000')
  });
 }])
```

2) You appear to have two apps. Instead of throwing angular.module() all over, define it in one place:

```
var app = angular.module('starter', []);
```

Then you can use it elsewhere like so:

```
app
  .service('SocketService, [.... etc
```

See that in action in the second part of 1)